# Google Maps V3 APIs terms of service

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a Web Application (based on Google Maps API V3).
Whenever an user clicks on a map, a marker is placed on that point and
an "human readable" address is resolved (by the geocoding service). In
this way I can put in an infowindow, attached to that marker, the
corresponding address.

The question is: Can I resolve just one time that address and store it
on an external DB? Is this practice compliant with your terms of
service?

Regards

Comment: Is this not covered in their online T&Cs? Would you add the relevant hyperlink in your question?

Answer (score 1):

The relevant section of the TOS is

10.1.3 Restrictions against Data Export or Copying.

(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store. ***For example, you must not use the Content to create an independent database of “places.”***

This precludes the use of reverse geocoding.

Comment: Why does Google teach a tutorial where you can actually save lat lng? https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3  Isn't this content saved for good, up and beyond of limited amounts for improving your app?

Comment: @user2060451 The key words are **limited** & **temporarily**.ie  you can store a limited amount of coordinates temporary for use with a map.These limits will be based on your needs but should not create a permanent database.

Answer (score 0):

no, this is forbidden by the terms of use by google.

we would have done it your way in another project, but we had to change because of the terms of use.